# Check django Cursor Programming Error and Handle accordingly

Tags: django, postgresql, database-cursor

I have a code to create a materialized view using Django Cursor. If the view already exists, it gives `Programming Error: Relation already exists.` I want to handle this case, and check if this error comes, it instead run another query

```
Refresh materialized view
```

But I am unable to check for error message using

```
cursor.statusmessage
```

it gives empty string.
Any other way to do this ?

Comment: If the code is raising an Exception (Programming Error) from what I can see, then you should use Try/Catch

Comment: yeah, but I need to verify why the ProgrammingError occured. It can be because of multiple reasons. It can be `Syntax error` , or `relation already exists`, or some other reason may be. I want to handle only the case where the `relation already exists`. If I get this error, I will call `Refresh materialized view` otherwise not.

Comment: though, I think I have figured out another way to do this. May be I can just first check if the table already exists through code. And then decide whether I need `create` query or `refresh `query. Instead of relying on the `create` query error

Comment: You can check if `e.message` contains `Relation already exists` (where `e` is the exception) ? Always check if the table exists is more of an anti-pattern for python (you are asking for permission instead of asking for forgiveness - check [here](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/asking_for_permission_instead_of_forgiveness_when_working_with_files.html#asking-for-permission-instead-of-forgiveness)

Comment: Thanks @Todor , didn't know about this anti-pattern for Python.This was a useful information for me. Will Try your approach.